How can I use the Constraints property field in the AnyLogic Optimisation Experiment?
I want to define constraints in the AnyLogic Optimisation Experiment, using the Constraints property field. Let's say I want to minimise staff costs and my decision variables are the numbers of staff from a specific type. The constraint is that the overall number of staff needs to be smaller or equal to 10. How can I define this constraint in the Optimisation Experiment?
I have read in other posts that I could use the Requirements property field instead, but as the Constraints property field is offered, there should be a way of utilising it.

Have you... checked the help? It is described well: https://anylogic.help/anylogic/experiments/optimization.html#constraints . Or do you have a specific question of "this code does not work?" . This place works best for you if you ask very focused, specific questions on 1 AnyLogic issue, show exactly what you tried already and where you are stuck. If you want to know “how do I best do X in AnyLogic”, you should use the LinkedIn forum instead. Check this overview to the community to understand why: https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-community.

also, you can use only the "anylogic" tag, that suffices

Thanks for the tips on posting. I will keep them in mind for the next time. Problem: The AnyLogic help does not provide a meaningful example. I also checked the tutorial video for the optimisation experiment, which seems to avoid the use of constraints. I have tried to set up an optimisation experiment for the Emergency Department example from the models found in the AnyLogic Help model library. Specific constraint: I want to ensure that the overall number of staff stays below 18. I want to check this before running the simulation, hence I want to use it as a constraint.

Cool. Share the details of what you tried, how it fails, what you expect to see and we can help :) . Some more tips specifically for SOF: https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-stackoverflow
